# Are there any cons to a semi singleton?

Tags: objective-c, singleton

I just solved a really weird problem I had where I needed this class to behave sort of like a singleton but not really. Here's a code snippet

```
@implementation HMFPicturePreviewModalPanel

__weak static UIViewController            *presentingInventoryViewController = nil;
       static HMFPicturePreviewModalPanel *sharedPicturePreviewModalPanel    = nil;

+(void)showPopupWithImage:(UIImage *)image withStartPoint:(CGPoint)startPoint withStartView:(UIView *)startView {

    //this checks if there is already a panel visible.
    if (![presentingInventoryViewController.view viewWithTag:kHMFPicturePreviewModalPanelTag]) {
        sharedPicturePreviewModalPanel = [[HMFPicturePreviewModalPanel alloc] initWithFrame:presentingInventoryViewController.view.bounds withimage:image];
        [presentingInventoryViewController.view addSubview:sharedPicturePreviewModalPanel];
        [sharedPicturePreviewModalPanel showFromPoint:[startView convertPoint:startPoint toView:presentingInventoryViewController.view]];
    }
}

+(void)changePresentingInventoryViewController:(UIViewController *)newInventoryViewController {
    [sharedPicturePreviewModalPanel removeFromSuperView];
    presentingInventoryViewController = newInventoryViewController;
}

+(void)removePresentingInventoryViewController {
    [sharedPicturePreviewModalPanel removeFromSuperView];
    presentingInventoryViewController = nil;
}
```

Is this called a semi-singleton? There's only ever going to be one of these on the screen at a time. I had to recreate this each time for it to work, hence why I couldn't do it as just a singleton.

What are the cons to this solution?
Also is it okay to have a __weak static variable?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you're trying to do here, but why the static variables can't be ivars in `HMFPicturePreviewModalPanel` instead?

Comment: Because those variables need to be static. If I made them instance variables then they couldn't be static right? They'd be specific to that instance right? I know this is really weird looking, but it works and I want to know if this is a bad idea.

Comment: Yeah... This is a terrible idea.  You're trying to change local state into global state, and in doing so have destroyed any semblance of program logic.

Comment: The biggest problem I had was the "initWithFrame" method. I have to call that but in doing so I would destroy the singleton if I used that model.

Comment: I don't see how this is different from a normal singleton, except it gets recreated each time "showPopup" is called.

Comment: @Hackmodford it may work, but if other people can't understand the logic in the code, then that logic is probably a bad idea :)

Comment: I'm sure I could explain it if I could show more. Since no one can say why this is a bad idea except that they can't understand it, I will take it that there are no cons except maybe the code not being crystal clear. It's a singleton that gets recreated each time because I am subclassing someone else's code.